# Rvest web scraping how to get the next pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler, rvest, httr

I need your help to navigate into the next pages of a website, which is programmed like that:

<'p' style="text-align:center; margin-top: 10px;">
                  <'p' class='paging-controls'>« Previous  1  <'b'>2  3  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(300)'>4  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(400)'>5  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(500)'>6  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(600)'>7  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(700)'>8  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(800)'>9  <'a class='number' href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(900)'>10    <'a href='#' onclick='SubmitClicked(200)'>Next »

I need to click on next to get the next page and so on using a loop

Comment: This depends on the format of the website. Some pages, when clicked will change an element of the URL. If this is the case then you can just alter the page in the url you scrape. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest should be able to help

Comment: Please include the website url and your coding attempt to far and indicate what isn't working.

Comment: you need login and password to get the data from https://www.lorryspotting.com

THat is what I did, but there is no page number in the URL. So I need just to click on next or any page number  via javascript